# Returning a class in Lua

Tags: lua

I'm trying to create a plugin but I can't seem to access the returned player class from outside the GetPlayer() function.

This is the GetPlayer Fuction:

```
function GetPlayer(Player_To_Find) -- This is the function we use to verify the user exists, It will return the user class if the user exists
    LOG("Finding " .. Player_To_Find) --False if they do not exist
    local Found = false
    local FindPlayer = function(TargetPlayer)
        if (TargetPlayer:GetName() == Player_To_Find) then
            Found = true
            print("Found " .. TargetPlayer:GetName())
            return TargetPlayer

        end
    end
    cRoot:Get():FindAndDoWithPlayer(Player_To_Find, FindPlayer)
    if Found == true then return TargetPlayer  else return false end
end
```

If I try to call the TargetPlayer class after it has returned using this snippet:

```
TargetPlayer=GetPlayer(Target)
if TargetPlayer ~= false then
    LOG(TargetPlayer:GetName())
```

It will fail with the error:

```
attempt to index global 'TargetPlayer' (a nil value)
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction, It's taken me a long time and I've come up blank.

Comment: A plugin for what exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter `TargetPlayer` is only in scope in the function body. The `TargetPlayer` in the last line of `GetPlayer` refers to a global variable, which is presumably nonexistent and therefore `nil`.

Declare a local variable in the `GetPlayer` function, set it in the body of the `FindPlayer` function, and return it at the end of the of `GetPlayer` (also don't return `false` if a player can't be found, return `nil`, which semantically means "nothing").

Comment: Thank you very much! I can't believe I missed that.